# How to open app specific files in Android using C?

Tags: java, android, c, kotlin

The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-access-store-files) show how to open app-specific files by calling `val file = File(context.filesDir, filename)` or `context.openFileOutput()`, but I need to open a file in a C library where the `context` is not available.

Is it possible to open app-specific files in Android from a C library, and if so, how can you get the file path to pass to something like `fopen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass your specific path as an argument to your function in C and use it with `fopen`.

To define your function in C and calling it in Kotlin side please read [this document](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni#ci).

When you pass your `String` variable as argument, you need to convert it to a regular C string type (char*).
So you can use this example:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_readFile(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
    jstring name)
{
    const char *path= (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,name,0);
    // use fopen and other stuff
    // release this string when done with it
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, name, str);
}
```

to access your app-specific directory (/data/data/{package-name}/), you don't need any permission declaration.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wasn't putting together that context.filesDir was just the String representation of the app-specific directory path. Thanks!